# Sum of item price in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The items are saved on firebase db. I am using *ngFor and need to sum the itemPrices (making it bill value)

`

```
this.angFire.list('/Items').subscribe((items) => {
      this.priceTotal = 0;
      this.items.forEach((item) => {
        this.priceTotal += this.itemPrice;
        return this.priceTotal;
      })
    })
```

`

I tried replacing this.item with item.itemPrice but it shows FirebaseListObservable error:

```
Property 'itemPrice' does not exist on type 'number[]'
```

Comment: I don't see a single `this.item` in the code you gave. Your error doesn't come from your snippet.

Comment: will you please console.log(this.itemPrice); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to add to `this.priceTotal` seeing as `this.itemPrice` is never clearly defined... I'm guessing you're just trying to sum the price of the items and assign the sum to `this.priceTotal`. This should maybe do the trick then.

```
this.angFire.list('/Items').subscribe((items) => {
    this.priceTotal = 0;
    this.priceTotal = items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + Number(item.itemPrice);
    })
})
```

PS, there is no `this.items`, unless you defined it somewhere else, `items` is block scoped to the `subscribe` function. So if we we're to keep it the way you wrote it, it should look like...

```
this.angFire.list('/Items').subscribe((items) => {
    this.priceTotal = 0;
    items.forEach((item) => {
        this.priceTotal += Number(item.itemPrice);
    })
})
```

Comment: PS, there is no `this.items`, unless you defined it somewhere else, `items` is block scoped to the `subscribe` function.

Comment: result is `[object Object]50` .. I have 2 itemPrice with value 100 and 50... the result seems to concatenate???

Comment: In your subscribe can you `console.log(items)` so we can see what the data returned is structured as?

Comment: `(2) [Object, Object]0: ObjectitemBrand: "Lays"itemName: "Finger Chips"itemPrice: "100"itemQuantity: "1"itemUnit: "units"$exists: function ()$key: "-Kn0TMhHLzMd5d-2c3Zz"__proto__: Object1: ObjectitemBrand: "Parle"itemName: "Biscuit"itemPrice: "50"itemQuantity: "1"itemUnit: "inches"$exists: function ()$key: "-Kn2SISWce-xmlbztJfh"__proto__: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Ok, that format looks hella weird.... but also it shows that `itemPrice` seems to be stored as string, not numbers. Updating my answer. (also if you wouldn't mind, run this too `console.log(Array.isArray(items))`

Comment: Absolutely correct! I missed the firebase provider declaration... changed to number and the formula works fine. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.angFire.list('/Items').subscribe((items: any) => {
  this.priceTotal = 0;
  this.items.forEach((item: any) => {
    this.priceTotal += item.itemPrice;
    return this.priceTotal;
  })
})
```